# Convert (or re-compress) bitmap/raster images embedded in an SVG?

Tags: svg

It is possible to embed bitmap/raster images into an SVG (via the image tag).

Is there a tool (preferable command line) to change the format or the compression of the embedded bitmaps? For example, I have an SVG with an embedded PNG bitmap image. I'm looking for a tool that could be called like

```
svgconvertertool -convert_embedded_pngs_to_jpg -compression high  -f original.svg -out result.svg
```

creating a new svg with is similar to the original svg, except that all embedded pngs are converted to jpg.

Background: I want to reduce the file size of a couple of SVGs. The file size is basically determined by the embedded PNGs, which I want to convert to (low-quality) JPGs.

Does imagemagick knows that trick?

Comment: A similar question can be found here: https://superuser.com/questions/273862/resampling-embedded-raster-images-in-svg

Answer (score 4):

Since I haven't found a tool I wrote a [Java based solution](https://github.com/JensN4/png_to_jpg_in_svg). This can be run via

```
java -cp "«pathto»/png_to_jpg_in_svg/bin" PNG_to_JPG_in_SVG «file|folder»
```

It can either process a single SVG «file» or all SVGs transitively contained in «folder». If an embedded PNG is found, it is replaced with an JPG version. Since JPG does not support transparency, the background is set to white. The compression quality is set to 50%.

When I was done I found that Florian Eßer has published a [python script](https://gist.github.com/flesser/3f9c80ff42879cad41bf) doing the same trick. His tool requires Python and uses the Python Imaging Library (PIL).

Maybe there is a way of using command line tools such as sed and imagemagick to do the trick, but I haven't found a working script which extracts/replaces the embedded files so that imagemagick can work with that. Alas I didn't find a suitable command in Inkscape.

---

PS: I'm pretty surprised that someone "downrated" my question. In our case, I was able to reduce the file size of SVGs exported by Sketch (which has a lousy SVG export) by a factor of 4! If someone knows about another tool, I would be happy to hear about it.